# Gulp watch with Livereload reloading when the page is reloaded, or by itself

Tags: sass, gulp, livereload

I have an infuriating problem that recently cropped up that I can't figure out: when my gulp watch task is running, the sass task will trigger if I manually refresh the page Livereload is watching (it will claim screen.css has been touched), and will then continue to trigger without me making any changes to watched files in the background, as if it's accumulating "watches" until MING will eventually crash or become so bogged down with tasks as to become unusuable.

One thing I noticed: if the sass task specifies any depth of directory, it causes the error:

```
'styles/sass/**/*.scss' (will trigger when partials are touched, or page is refreshed; goes insane eventually) 
'styles/sass/*.scss' (only triggers when screen.scss is touched as expected)
```

So my suspicion is something is amiss with sass globbing.

**Things I have tried:**

- Reverting all my sass-related or livereload gulp packages to match that of another local site that doesn't do this
- Making sure screen.css isn't modified by the CMS (it did have filemtime() on it originally)
- Removing all partials in screen.scss
- Turning off Windows File History

**A simplified version of my gulpfile:**

```
    var gulp            = require('gulp');
    var sass            = require('gulp-sass');
    var livereload      = require('gulp-livereload');
    var cleancss        = require('gulp-clean-css');
    var rename          = require('gulp-rename');
    var notify          = require('gulp-notify');
    var plumber         = require('gulp-plumber');
    var autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    var sassglob        = require('gulp-sass-glob');
    var sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

    gulp.task('sass', function(){
        return gulp.src('styles/sass/screen.scss')
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: function(err) {
                notify.onError({
                            title:    "Gulp: [sass]",
                            subtitle: "Error",
                            message:  "<%= error.message %>",
                            sound:    false
                        })(err);
    
                this.emit('end');
            }}))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sassglob())
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(autoprefixer({
                cascade: false
            }))
            .pipe(cleancss({
                compatibility: '*',
    
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('styles'))
            .pipe(livereload())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            done();
    });
    
    gulp.task('watch', function(done){
        livereload.listen();
        gulp.watch(['styles/sass/**/**/*.scss'], { usePolling: true }, gulp.series(['sass']));
        gulp.watch(['../*.php','../templates/**/*.php','../partials/**/*.php'], { usePolling: true }).on('change', livereload.changed);
    });
    
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['sass', 'watch']));
```

**My screen.scss pulls in all my scss like so. These go down several directories deep and compile to screen.css.**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/*
utilities
*/
@import "utility/**/*";

/*
vendor
*/
@import "vendor/**/*";

/*
globals
*/
@import "globals/**/*";

/*
modules
*/
@import "modules/**/**/*";

/*
templates
*/
@import "templates/**/*";
```

Again, my general setup has worked fine for years, so I wonder if it's a new version of one of the gulp packages that's freshly messing this up?

**Finally, my file structure:**

```
/assets/
/assets/styles/
/assets/styles/sass/
/assets/styles/sass/globals/ ...
/assets/styles/sass/modules/ ...
/assets/styles/sass/components/ ...
/assets/styles/sass/screen.scss
/assets/styles/screen.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, dumb:

I had a function inside the CMS that writes a sass partial when the page refreshes.